# Python2.7 subprocess32: how to share environment between two scripts executed via Popen?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have 2 scripts: 1. Config one, which modifies about 20 environment variables and runs another small script inside, and 2. The process one which uses environment variables set by script1 to do something.

I tried to execute them one by one via Python2.7 subprocess32.Popen() and pass the same env variable to both Popen. No success, environments from script1 are just empty for script2

```
import os
import subprocess32 as subprocess
my_env = os.environ
subprocess.Popen(script1, env=my_env)
subprocess.Popen(script2, env=my_env)
```

How I could actually share environment between 2 scripts?

Comment: The right thing to do is define a wrapper script that calls `script1` and `script2`, then run the wrapper from Python, as neither of your original scripts are really standalone scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the first subprocess exits, the changes to its environment are gone.  Such changes are only propagated to its own subprocess.  You need to do something like this:

```
import shlex

subprocess.Popen(". {}; {}".format(shlex.quote(script1),
                                   shlex.quote(script2)), 
                 shell=True)
```

But as always, using `shell=True` can introduce security issues.

Comment: Thank you so much, that did work. And I verified that os.environ is not modified after Popen execution.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is in `my_env=my_env`, second parameter need to be `env`.

```
my_env = os.environ
subprocess.Popen(script1, env=my_env)
my_env = os.environ
subprocess.Popen(script2, env=my_env)
```

Comment: thank you to fix a misprint. The problem still persists, unfortunately.

Comment: if you change `environments` in first script, try to get one more time the env, i update my answer

Comment: thank you, but os.environ is not modified after Popen execution. It seems that the only way is to execute scripts in a raw in one Popen